# Is there any word "Numerical power" in sociology?

Tags: sociology

I was thinking about how population influences the power dynamics in a polity. The community that has the majority has more say in political discourse. Can we use the term "Numerical power" to describe the power of such a community? Would it be sociologically correct to say so?

Comment: Democracy somethign something

Comment: **Tyranny of the majority** incorporates the ancient and well-known concept that the numerical majority can impose its will on the numerical minority in a democracy that makes political decisions purely on the numerical tally of one person one vote.

Comment: @SystemTheory Tyranny of the majority neglects the fact that it's not easy to get a majority and that even in that case it wouldn't by tyranny as it had a democratic mandate and thus would rely on a majority rather than being able to decide on a whim. It's a scarecrow of people in favor of a tyranny.

Comment: @haxor Despite objections the concept called **tyranny of the majority** is ancient and well known. **Strength in numbers** is another well-known phrase. Many people think democratic socialism is a viable political system. But even democratic socialism is a system in which the majority socialist is punching down on the minority individual who hates the rules imposed by the majority. Capitalism in which the Oligarchs or authoritarian party captures the government is tyranny of the minority under the ruse of democratic republic. Any moralistic regime rationalizes its misuse of the police force.

Answer (score 0):

It is a form of speech that is used, but it's rare, and a bit awkward.

You have to make a case for why greater numbers mean greater power. For instance, pensioners are very likely to vote, under 25 year olds are not, so in elections numbers do not equate to political influence.

National or regional majorities, might usually fill the role, relating to voting potential. Or cohesive power block, referring to groups with very similar politics, or highly motivated by specific issues.